# wtf validate on submit only the token, not the fields

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I use Flask WTF and their token to prevent cross site attacks.  My pages can consist of many fields, some of which are not relevant and contain no user data on POST.  I have separate form submissions for various fields, but Flask validates ALL fields on the entire page, not just the ones in the form submit.
Is there a function in Flask to validate only the token on submit, and not ALL the fields on the entire page, because after validation a redirect back to the page will visually error the non-relevant fields.

I understand that I can use a script before POST to disable the non-relevant fields, but this method seems in excess.

Thanks,
Cliff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Optional` validator so empty fields return no errors as they are specifically not required.

You can also hook into the validation process and write your own script such as this snippet http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/64/

You could use define multiple forms which reference different fields on the page depending on which form is submitted on the page.

You may be able to make use of the pre_validate function defined here http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#the-field-base-class, although I have not used this myself.

Comment: Excellent assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: Can someone give him an up vote, I'm not allowed yet = newbie.

Comment: you might not be able to upvote but you can accept the answer as the correct one which is helpful. cheerrs